# WPF C# - Incorrect mouse position coordinate

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to draw a selection by drawing rectangle on an Image but it seems that the selection is off by a huge margin. Here is my code.

EdgeDetectionWindow.xaml

```
    <Window x:Class="SenpiCHC.EdgeDetectionWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SenpiCHC"
        xmlns:codeg="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="EdgeDetectionWindow" Width="1270" Height="720"
        WindowState="Maximized"
        WindowStyle="None">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="dataFromEnum" 
                            MethodName="GetValues"
                            ObjectType="{x:Type codeg:Enum}">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="local:SelectedEdgeDetectionType"/>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>

        </ObjectDataProvider>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Image x:Name="imgDynamic" 
                   MouseDown="ImgDynamic_MouseDown"
                   MouseMove="ImgDynamic_MouseMove"
                   MouseUp="ImgDynamic_MouseUp"
                   Width="1000"
                   Height="562"/>
            <Button Content="Select file" 
                Margin="30"
                Width="100" 
                x:Name="selectFileBtn"
                Click="SelectFileBtn_Click"/>

            <ComboBox Margin="10"
                      Width="100"
                      x:Name="edgeDetectionCbox"
                      SelectionChanged="EdgeDetectionCbox_SelectionChanged"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource dataFromEnum}}">
            </ComboBox>

            <Button Content="Detect now!" 
                    Margin="30"
                    Width="100" 
                    x:Name="detectBtn" 
                    Click="DetectBtn_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

EdgeDetectionWindow.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class EdgeDetectionWindow : Window
{

    Image<Bgr, byte> _imgInput;

    private bool IsSelecting = false;
    private double X0, Y0, X1, Y1;
    private Bitmap ImageCopy;

    public EdgeDetectionWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SelectFileBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            Uri fileUri = new Uri(openFileDialog.FileName);
            imgDynamic.Source = new BitmapImage(fileUri); // Why bitmapimage? //put the imagefile into the window
            ImageCopy = new Bitmap(openFileDialog.FileName);

            _imgInput = new Image<Bgr, byte>(openFileDialog.FileName);
        }
    }

    private void ImgDynamic_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        IsSelecting = true;
        X0 = e.GetPosition(imgDynamic).X;
        Y0 = e.GetPosition(imgDynamic).Y;
    }

    private void ImgDynamic_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsSelecting) return;


        //Save the final point
        X1 = e.GetPosition(this.imgDynamic).X;
        Y1 = e.GetPosition(this.imgDynamic).Y;

        //Make a bitmap to display the rectangle
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(ImageCopy);

        //Draw the rectangle
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
        {
            gr.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red,
                (float)Math.Min(X0, X1), (float)Math.Min(Y0, Y1),
                (float)Math.Abs(X0 - X1), (float)Math.Abs(Y0 - Y1));
        }

        //Display the rectangle
        imgDynamic.Source = BitmapToImageSource(bm);
    }

    private void ImgDynamic_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsSelecting) return;
        IsSelecting = false; //reset the value

        //Display the rectangle
        imgDynamic.Source = BitmapToImageSource(ImageCopy);
    }

    private void EdgeDetectionCbox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void DetectBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (edgeDetectionCbox.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals("Canny"))
        {
            //Receive input from inputbox
            CannyInputDialogue popup = new CannyInputDialogue();
            popup.ShowDialog();
            int tresh = int.Parse(popup.Tresh);
            int treshLinking = int.Parse(popup.TreshLinking);

            //Do canny
            //Create grayscale
            Image<Gray, byte> _imgCanny = new Image<Gray, byte>(_imgInput.Width, _imgInput.Height, new Gray(0)); //canny  with 0 intensity gray image
            _imgCanny = _imgInput.Canny(tresh, treshLinking);

            //Display the image because imgDynamic.Source cannot display image from emgucv directly
            Bitmap display = _imgCanny.ToBitmap();
            imgDynamic.Source = BitmapToImageSource(display);


        }
        else if (edgeDetectionCbox.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals("RobertCross"))
        {
            //Do robertcross

        }
        else if (edgeDetectionCbox.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals("Laplacian"))
        {
            //Do laplacian
            LaplacianInputDialogue popup = new LaplacianInputDialogue();
            popup.ShowDialog();
            int apertureSize = int.Parse(popup.ApertureSize);
            //Do grayscale
            Image<Gray, byte> _imgGray = _imgInput.Convert<Gray, byte>(); //somehow it has to be converted(?)

            //Do sobel
            Image<Gray, float> _imgLaplacian = new Image<Gray, float>(_imgInput.Width, _imgInput.Height); //canny  with 0 intensity gray image
            _imgLaplacian = _imgGray.Laplace(apertureSize);

            //Display the image because imgDynamic.Source cannot display image from emgucv directly
            Bitmap display = _imgLaplacian.ToBitmap();
            imgDynamic.Source = BitmapToImageSource(display);

        }
        else if (edgeDetectionCbox.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals("Sobel"))
        {
            //Receive input from inputbox
            SobelInputDialogue popup = new SobelInputDialogue();
            popup.ShowDialog();
            int xorder = int.Parse(popup.Xorder);
            int yorder = int.Parse(popup.Yorder);
            int apertureSize = int.Parse(popup.ApertureSize);

            //Do grayscale
            Image<Gray, byte> _imgGray = _imgInput.Convert<Gray, byte>(); //somehow it has to be converted(?)

            //Do sobel
            Image<Gray, float> _imgSobel = new Image<Gray, float>(_imgInput.Width, _imgInput.Height); //canny  with 0 intensity gray image
            _imgSobel = _imgGray.Sobel(xorder, yorder, apertureSize);

            //Display the image because imgDynamic.Source cannot display image from emgucv directly
            Bitmap display = _imgSobel.ToBitmap();
            imgDynamic.Source = BitmapToImageSource(display);

        }


    }

    BitmapImage BitmapToImageSource(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Save(memory, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            memory.Position = 0;
            BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapimage.BeginInit();
            bitmapimage.StreamSource = memory;
            bitmapimage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmapimage.EndInit();

            return bitmapimage;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried putting the e.GetPosition() parameter to this or imgDynamic but it is still off by a huge margin. Is there any workaround for this? I am sorry if my code is extremely messy as I am still trying to learn more about it.

Comment: First of all, you should not use the WinForms System.Drawing.Bitmap class in a WPF application. In order to draw a selection rectangle on top of an image, use a Rectangle. Then create a CroppedBitmap from the source BitmapImage. If you would give a detailed explanation of your actual goal, we might be able to provide a more suitable approach.

Comment: I am planning to create an application in which the user will select the region of which the user determines it as an object and apply edge detection on the selected region. Then the application will calculate the area of the object(after applying edge detection) in pixels. I still don't know how to do that though.

Answer (score 0):

In order to draw a selection rectangle over an image, you could simply have a Path element with a RectangleGeometry on top of an Image, like this:

```
<Canvas>
    <Image Source="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg"
           MouseLeftButtonDown="ImageMouseLeftButtonDown"
           MouseLeftButtonUp="ImageMouseLeftButtonUp"
           MouseMove="ImageMouseMove"/>

    <Path x:Name="selectionPath" Stroke="Magenta" StrokeThickness="2"/>
</Canvas>
```

With these event handlers:

```
private Point mousePos;

private void ImageMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var image = (Image)sender;

    image.CaptureMouse();
    mousePos = e.GetPosition(image);
    selectionPath.Data = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(mousePos, mousePos));
}

private void ImageMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var image = (Image)sender;

    image.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    selectionPath.Data = null;
}

private void ImageMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var rect = selectionPath.Data as RectangleGeometry;

    if (rect != null)
    {
        var image = (Image)sender;

        rect.Rect = new Rect(mousePos, e.GetPosition(image));
    }
}
```